# how to use previousState in react hooks using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I trying to understand how to understand how to use previous state using react hooks in typescript.

The code below works, but you will have to ignore the error which is: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.`

Yes, that makes sense as you can't cast number to HTMLDivElement, but what is the right way to implement previous state in react hooks?

Eventually I would like to use it in DetailsList (fluentui) to handle items when they are deleted.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

  export function Counter() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const prevCountRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement|null>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
      prevCountRef.current = count;
    }, [count]);
    return (
      <h1>
        Now: {count}, before: {prevCountRef.current}

        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>Increment</button>
      </h1>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React ref should be typed to match exactly what it is storing. Typing `prevCountRef` as `HTMLDivElement|null` is incorrect. It should be `number` to match the `count` state type that you are caching in the ref. You can initialize the ref value to the initial state value as well to avoid any undefined or null typing.

Example:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
const prevCountRef = useRef<number>(count);
useEffect(() => {
  prevCountRef.current = count;
}, [count]);
```

Comment: wow, great! I actually changed it to useRef<number>(null); before, but it seems had forgotten to remove the null and replace it with count. Great, thanks a bunch.